# Drawing an image in ios6 using kineticJS

Tags: ios6, kineticjs

In ios5,when i try to draw an image using KineticJS,it gets drawn perfectly.But whereas in ios6, when i try to draw an image using KineticJS, the image gets drawn 2-3 times bigger(compared to that in ios5) automatically.Why is this happening?. Is it some resolution problem?. How do i resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

are you setting the correct meta viewport to define the page size?

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml

Comment: I even tried that.But it has not fetched me the desired result.(btw, you are a big inspiration for novices like me)

Comment: I tried mentioning the meta viewport but it made no difference in my app. I am facing the same issue in my app too.